# How to serialize json data in order to fake trip the server?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I am trying to serialize the json data when the submit button in clicked in my code in order to "fake trip" the server. How do I do this in javascript? Here is my javascript code so far. I really don't even know where to begin when it comes to fake trip a server. And I've looked up serialized JSON data, and my JSON is already in that form.

```
//var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
//form.setAttribute("method", "POST");

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))


if (data == null) {
  data = new Array();
}

var add = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
add.setAttribute("onclick", "validate()");
//console.log(add);

function remove(obj) {
  console.log(data);
  var item_to_delete = obj.id;
  data.splice(item_to_delete,1);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(obj.id);
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
  location.reload();
}

function validate() {

  var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
  var relation = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value;
  var is_smoker = document.getElementsByName("smoker")[0].checked

  if (is_smoker) {
    smoker = "Yes";
  }
  else {
    smoker = "No";
  }

  if (age.length == 0 || relation == "") {
    alert ("Please fill out the form")
  }

  else {

    var myObj = {"age": age, "relation": relation, "smoker":smoker};

    data.push(myObj);

    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))

  }

}

var debug = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];

//console.log(debug)


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  debug.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + i + "' onclick = 'remove(this)'>Age: " +
                     data[i].age + " ||| Relationship: " +
                     data[i].relation + " ||| Smoker? " +
                     data[i].smoker + "</li>"
}
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by fake trip to the server? If you mean using ajax to fetch data then fetch a text.json file on local server. That would be similar to a call to a backend

Comment: @johan i'm honestly not sure. i've been given this part of a team project and my instructions were as follows: ***Serialize as JSON upon form submission as a fake trip to the server.***

Comment: Ok so any trip to the server means ajax. Whatever the url is then doesnt matter. Just write the xhr code

Comment: @johan so, what would that look like, i no nothing about ajax.

Comment: Google jquery ajax and copy some code, no one is going to write it for you